# Information loss function for numerical approximations

Tags: numerical-methods, information-theory

The other day I was reading about some aspects in information including Shannon's source coding theorem and other interesting ideas. Coming from a computational/numerical mathematics background I was wondering about the following:

When formulating a numerical approximation, say approximating a function using a polynomial, or solving a differential equation using finite difference schemes, one loses information about the original function or the ture solution to the differential equation (assuming for sake of argument that there exists a solution). Now my question:

Could there be a way to write down a function which quantifies the loss of information when applying an approximation?

I understand that this function could have numerous inputs, and perhaps is not the most practical method of determining how good an approximation is. However, I would like to have a general idea if this is possible in principle, and how one might construct such a function.

Comment: Just thinking loud: is it a loss or a gain of information ?  An analytical representation is extremely compact. Say $y=\sin x$ might be less than $100$ bits of information. Can you still lose some ?

Comment: My apologies, but I'm not entirely sure what you are asking. My thought process is, taking $y = sin(x)$ as an example, that if I approximate  this function with say a Taylor polynomial up to degree $n$, I would lose information.

Comment: My question is loss or gain ? What if you trade 50 bits for 500 bits ?

Comment: I would say thats a gain in information; going from 50 to 500 bits. Maybe one could put a bound on the information gained by saying that the analytical solution contains the maximum amount of information.

Comment: You mean minimum, don't you ?

Comment: Yes, of course, my bad!

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no well-defined quantitative measure of information.